# can't get NgOptimizedImage to be responsive in Angular 15

Tags: html, angular, responsive-images

In an Angular 15.1.x project, i'm trying implement an image that is responsive on mobile and desktop using NgOptimizedImage. The mandatory img width and height attributes are overriding the sizes attribute.

`<img ngSrc="image.png" width="617" height="505" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 276w, 317w">`.

According to the docs, this should mean if viewport 768px or less image width should display 276px wide otherwise 317px. I'm using the intrinsic for width/height as per docs. The image always shows at whatever the width/height attribute is (617px X 505px).

Essentially i'm trying to achieve this but using ngSrc:

`<img src="image.png" srcset="img.png 617w" sizes="(max-width: 768px) 276px, 317px" >`

Comment: Have you find any answer to this topic? 
I'm on the same quest :D